# How to get the inner texts of option tags in a List?

Tags: java, list, selenium

I've been trying to get all the elements of a dropdown list `<option>` tag inner texts with no avail,
I've been getting them into a `List<WebElement>` and trying to extract them into a `List<String>`
but I've been getting empty line breaks when I use `System.out.println()` on the `List<String>`

```
List<WebElement> saOptions = element("<omitted-xpath-element>",
             tierType.getTierName().getRealValue(),
             tierType.getTierDescription().getRealValue())
             .getAllOptions();

List<String> oriSaRules = saOptions
            .stream()
            .map(e->e.getText())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

saOptions.forEach(e->System.out.println(e.getText()));
```

Also tried this to get a List:

```
List<String> saOptions = element("<omitted-xpath-element>",
                tierType.getTierName().getRealValue(),
                tierType.getTierDescription().getRealValue())
                .getAllInnerTexts();
```

Returns nothing though

Comment: You just want to print all the texts inside the option tag ? sample dom below

`<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>`

Comment: @WilfredClement Yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work

```
Select dd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cars")));
List<WebElement> dd_values = dd.getOptions();
        for(WebElement element:dd_values)
            System.out.println(element.getText());
```

Please import the select class as well